# How to add numeration to stanzas

Tags: numbering, verse, poetry

I would like to numerate my stanzas and not only my verses. I couldn't find any option in the `verse` package. Is there any workaround?

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}
\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-3em}
\poemtitle{Garden}
\poemlines{2}
\begin{verse}
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!

I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

What I would like to obtain is

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\trlap` macro of `stackengine` does this for you.  By placing it inside the macro `\nextverse` with an indexing counter, the result is achieved.  You will have to periodically reset the counter with `\setcounter{verseno}{0}` when you wish to start anew.

EDITED to ply my bardly skills at continuing the symbol-laden verse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcounter{verseno}
\def\nextverse{\stepcounter{verseno}\trlap{\Roman{verseno}}}
\begin{document}
\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-3em}
\poemtitle{Garden}
\poemlines{2}
\begin{verse}
\nextverse 
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!

\nextverse
How could this mishap happen? \\
My tool I yet can wield. \\
But that bachelor found his way there; \\
I had failed to plow the field.\\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You, of course, can tailor the effect, for example,

```
\def\nextverse{\stepcounter{verseno}\trlap{%
  \ifnum\theverseno>1\rule{0pt}{4ex}\fi\bfseries\Roman{verseno}}}
```

gives boldness to the numeration, and an extra gap for each `\nextverse` except the first:

[image]

Comment: +1: a typical example where `stackengine` definitely rules :)

Answer (score 2):

I would not set a new line, as the Roman numbers are not part of the poem. The counting would be confusing, imho.

I would suggest using the approach introduced with the `verse` package which looks like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}
\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-3em}
\poemtitle{Garden}
\poemlines{2}
\begin{verse}
\flagverse{I}I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!

\flagverse{II}I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image]